# How to retrieve multiple data at view passed from controller in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my controller file, to pass data to my view:

```
public function getDreams() {
    $dreams = Dream::all();
    $dreamsToReturn = $this->highlightWords($dreams);
    $disco = 1;
    $data = array('dreams' => $dreamsToReturn, 'disco' => $disco);
    return view('home')->with('data', $data);
}
```

I'm not having any problems with the `$dreamsToReturn`, I can display them in my view:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8 left-side">
    @if(count($data['dreams']) > 0)
        @foreach($data['dreams'] as $key=>$dream)
            <p class="dream-id small-padding">Álom {{sprintf("%03d", $key+1)}}</p>
            <p class="dream-body small-padding">{!!$dream->dream!!}</p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

However, I cant figure out, how to display the value of the `$disco` variable. This is what I'm trying:

```
<p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text"><? {{$data['disco']}} ?>%</p>
```

What is wrong, with this part?

Comment: Did you tried to dump the data `{{ dump($data) }}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove `<? ?>` from :

```
 <p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text"><? {{$data['disco']}} ?>%</p>
```

To

```
<p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text"> {{$data['disco']}} %</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to used this way 
use `compact` function `with`

```
return view('home')->with(compact('dreamsToReturn','disco'));
```

second way

```
return view('home', compact('dreamsToReturn','disco'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact` in the view function to return your array like so:

`return view('home', compact('data'));`

Or you can do them separately:

`return view('home', compact('dreamsToReturn', 'disco'));`

**EDIT:**

`<p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text"><? {{$data['disco']}} ?>%</p>`

Change this to:

`<p class="position-absolute position-percentage blue-text">{{$disco}}%</p>`

Comment: I still don't know how to display the disco data :( it still displays nothing

Comment: In your view `disco` becomes `$disco` and `dreamsToReturn` becomes `$dreamsToReturn`. So you can literally just call `$disco`.

Comment: $disco is still nothing

Comment: You have short-hand php tags to which inside you're also using blade templating. Remove the php tags as shown above so `<? {{$data['disco']}} ?>` becomes `{{$disco}} %`

Answer (score 0):

in controller side

```
class class_name extends Controller {
    public $view_data = [];

    public function function_name(){
        $this->view_data['variable_name'] = array('1','2','3');
        return view('view_name', $this->view_data);
    }
}
```

in view side

```
@foreach($variable_name as $v)
    <lable>{{$v}}</lable>
@endforeach
```